# DeleteReport leaves devices in Unresposive state

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

For my alexa smart home skill, I sent DeleteReport api request & received success response from the api.
Then I opened Alexa app on phone & now all the devices are unresponsive. When clicked on any device, nothing happens in the app & the devices now cannot be controlled via Alexa app.

The expected result here is all devices should disappear from the Alexa app.

Below is the DeleteReport response I received

```
{
  status: 202,
  statusText: 'Accepted',
  headers: {
    'content-length': '0',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    server: 'Server',
    date: 'Wed, 03 Jan 2024 08:35:57 GMT',
    'x-amz-rid': 'YWJNMJ09PT3EN3309HW9',
    'access-control-allow-headers': 'authorization,x-amz-access-token',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    status: '202',
    'x-amzn-requestid': '4f3af86b-e18e-4046-8173-f61bb5770428',
    vary: 'Content-Type,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload',
    'x-cache': 'Miss from cloudfront',
    via: '1.1 aebe2a57edb288ce1fe0507f1cddf390.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
    'x-amz-cf-pop': 'BOM54-P1',
    'x-amz-cf-id': '5Ips1C4hDvJgwTpnjpn-8Akmqf-FdnQH8nMfaj8fUAWY5gLtWcyJBQ=='
  },
  config: {
    url: 'https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v3/events',
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"event":{"header":{"namespace":"Alexa.Discovery","name":"DeleteReport","messageId":"a63095e0-c762-40e7-81c2-e86f86ab708d","payloadVersion":"3"},"payload":{"endpoints":[{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_5fe058d75a5d4280af4dac8c","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_5fe058e85a5d4280af4daeef","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_5fe058f85a5d4280af4db146","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_5fe059065a5d4280af4db3c0","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6155b3c3f73a470f1a99b441","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6155b3c3f73a470f1a99b444","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6155b3c3f73a470f1a99b447","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6155b3c3f73a470f1a99b44a","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6155b3c3f73a470f1a99b44d","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6155b3c3f73a470f1a99b450","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6155b3c3f73a470f1a99b453","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_624051971834676eb8c91867","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_624051971834676eb8c9186a","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_624051971834676eb8c9186d","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_624051971834676eb8c91870","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_624051971834676eb8c91873","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_624051971834676eb8c91876","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_624051971834676eb8c91879","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6241dc0a1834676eb8c9189c","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6241dc0a1834676eb8c9189f","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6241dc0a1834676eb8c918a2","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6241dc0a1834676eb8c918a5","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6241df551834676eb8c918b5","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6241df551834676eb8c918b8","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6251315fe3c91359aaf58777","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6251315fe3c91359aaf5877d","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6251315fe3c91359aaf58783","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6251315fe3c91359aaf58789","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6251315fe3c91359aaf5878f","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6251315fe3c91359aaf58795","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_6251315fe3c91359aaf5879b","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63a15adcc4f203bb7bcb9e3e","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63a15adcc4f203bb7bcb9e44","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63a15adcc4f203bb7bcb9e4a","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63a15adcc4f203bb7bcb9e50","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63a15adcc4f203bb7bcb9e56","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63a15adcc4f203bb7bcb9e5c","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63a15adcc4f203bb7bcb9e62","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63a15adcc4f203bb7bcb9e68","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63bbe66dc4f203bb7bcb9f2e","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63bbe66dc4f203bb7bcb9f34","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63bbe66dc4f203bb7bcb9f3a","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63bbe66dc4f203bb7bcb9f40","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63bbe66dc4f203bb7bcb9f46","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63bbe66dc4f203bb7bcb9f4c","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63bbe8dfc4f203bb7bcb9f59","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63bbe8dfc4f203bb7bcb9f5f","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63bbe8dfc4f203bb7bcb9f65","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["SWITCH"],"endpointId":"eid_63bbe8dfc4f203bb7bcb9f6b","friendlyName":"Iho Device","manufacturerName":"Integrated Home"},{"capabilities":[],"description":"Integrated Home Device","displayCategories":["'... 8811 more characters,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer Atza|IwEBIKZmJq7IddYUKFf78HRpm4FJEU2Au3k5EyYVFOvjsSnBBC4E7M-6V71-r23y7oiB12l-eaoFYlowv5V4hrdA4VM2ovQ91QRzsF9wrjnEXlAbVwR1LYQ8PQj6BOgy9Kgu4ZTLWCBT-Yc1oAFfeWeJAB-tGfZZLLFtnPupxDwWfqTNTZjSGAwFnLlUd3T8egc7l1DQSa_katlUx6maMmeGMwoZRTiCfYqE1bEoaEqvT-tkpDlmu6mRABSVD4XmE4MRHHv2Z_v3W9myX3KKQkR9BRsb',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1',
      'Content-Length': 18811
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: true,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 18811,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.eu.amazonalexa.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.eu.amazonalexa.com',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: null,
      [Symbol(alpncallback)]: null,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: -1,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [Timeout],
        _idleStart: 4195,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 68,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 66
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 1,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'POST /v3/events HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Bearer Atza|IwEBIKZmJq7IddYUKFf78HRpm4FJEU2Au3k5EyYVFOvjsSnBBC4E7M-6V71-r23y7oiB12l-eaoFYlowv5V4hrdA4VM2ovQ91QRzsF9wrjnEXlAbVwR1LYQ8PQj6BOgy9Kgu4ZTLWCBT-Yc1oAFfeWeJAB-tGfZZLLFtnPupxDwWfqTNTZjSGAwFnLlUd3T8egc7l1DQSa_katlUx6maMmeGMwoZRTiCfYqE1bEoaEqvT-tkpDlmu6mRABSVD4XmE4MRHHv2Z_v3W9myX3KKQkR9BRsb\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 18811\r\n' +
      'Host: api.eu.amazonalexa.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype],
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/v3/events',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: null,
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 202,
      statusMessage: 'Accepted',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v3/events',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 30,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.eu.amazonalexa.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 18811,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v3/events',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      authorization: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
    [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  data: ''
}
```

Comment: I tried sending a DeleteReport event on my end with Postman and was able to see the updated list of devices in the Alexa app with no issues. Did you try to update the Alexa app? I would suggest sharing the full JSON of the DeleteReport to help better investigate the issue.